# Yii2 and Reportico

Tags: yii2, reportico

currently i develop system for hospital but most likely for patients record tracking..i'm new in yii2 also reportico..currently still study, research & developing..now have to explore reportico.. i'm having problem to join two & many table..also not familiar enough with reportico sql..do you know where can i learn deeply about yii2 reportico other than reportico.org and http://www.reportico.org/yii2/web/index.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reportico just uses standard sql as found in mysql and postgres...so joins are just done using standard sql joins ...

What I suggest you do is go to the reportico sourceforge site here and get latest 4.5 which comes with tutorials.. You will learn to use joins here.... get it here ..

https://sourceforge.net/projects/reportico/files/?source=navbar

Extract  to a web folder and point your browser at it.. Then you can use the latest documentation to learn about reportico .. Everything you do will be applicable to the yii2 version..

http://www.reportico.org/documentation/4.5/doku.php?id=getting_started

And I think following the tutorials here will really help ..

http://www.reportico.org/documentation/4.5/doku.php?id=northwindtutorial

Good luck

Comment: Thanks Sir Peter Deed.. Your help so meaningful to me =')

Comment: Dear Sir Peter Deed,

I already download latest version 4.5 but the page cannot found in my application.. Before this I using version 4.3 and follow the installation procedure from http://www.reportico.org/yii2/web/index.php/site/installation and success..
May I know can i upgrade from 4.3 to 4.5 using composer? Thanks in advance =')

Comment: Hi Sir, I just now can view the reportico page with this url 

http://localhost/splp/vendor/reportico/yii2-reportico/components/run.php?project=admin&execute_mode=ADMIN&clear_session=1

I don't know is this the correct way to view reportico in my application..

Comment: After follow your 1st northwind tutorial, the sql like below (the error in next comment)

SELECT  ProductID id, ProductName product, northwind_categories.CategoryID, UnitsInStock in_stock, UnitsOnOrder on_order, ReorderLevel,  companyname Company, country, categoryname category
FROM northwind_products 
join northwind_suppliers on northwind_products.supplierid = northwind_suppliers.supplierid
join northwind_categories on northwind_products.categoryid = northwind_categories.categoryid
WHERE 1 = 1  
[ AND ProductID in ( {product_id} ) ]
ORDER BY categoryname

Comment: I got an error message when run report like this..

Main Report Query - Error: Query Failed

SELECT ProductID id, ProductName product, northwind_categories.CategoryID, UnitsInStock in_stock, UnitsOnOrder on_order, ReorderLevel, companyname Company, country, categoryname category FROM northwind_products join northwind_suppliers on northwind_products.supplierid = northwind_suppliers.supplierid join northwind_categories on northwind_products.categoryid = northwind_categories.categoryid WHERE 1 = 1 [ AND ProductID in ( {product_id} ) ] ORDER BY categoryname

Comment: Ok you cannot run from in laravel like that..i was suggesting you unpack that zip file to a completely diferrent folder .. for example into a top folder called reportico. Then point your browser at this folder. Now did you:

Comment: did you firstly configure tutorials from the admin page and did you run "Generate the tutorial tables"? .. if you did then the northwind_ tables will be ther .. In that last error is there anything after the last word category name that gives an idea of the error?

Comment: After try and error so many time now I can run the tutorial after click localhost/(appfolder)/vendor/reportico/yii2-reportico/components.. Then the url became like this http://localhost/splp/vendor/reportico/yii2-reportico/components/run.php?project=admin&execute_mode=ADMIN&clear_session=1

I still trying to understand, try and error that. Anyway thanks Sir Peter. =')